# How to make a background-image in an :after selecter stay on background and correct position?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to make a blockquote with an image as background before and after. :before is not a problem, but with the :after selector, the image stays on the foreground. Text disappears...

I tried different solutions with css, like display inline-block;giving the paragraph index:99 and so on.

The css:

```
blockquote p:after{
content:"";
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background:url("https://proef-domein.nl/chiropractic/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/quotes.png");
 margin-left:-30px;
 z-index:1;
 position:absolute}
```

The position is correct, but the image stays over the text instead of below the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it worked on my local install:

```
z-index:-1;
```

Comment: Make sure the parent has position relative

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with

```
position:absolute;
```

can you position absolute the text?
Maybe using another element in absolute for text?

After is always "next to" the element, and absolute is always above.